# How to automatically put your site into maintenance mode if at least a critical security update is available?

Tags: cron, security, maintenance-mode

I think I'm craving for this functionality.

What I want is, if after a CRON run, Drupal detects that such a security update is available, the site would be taken down for maintenance mode to avoid potential attacks. Well, quite paranoid here. It would be better if Apache can be made to serve a static page from another folder.

I have a vague idea in my mind that we can use drush in this. However, I can't think of how Drupal can "tell" some daemon/service or run some script if the trigger (critical security update available) is uhm, triggered.

I can't seem to find any solution to do this thing, so far. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This could be scripted however, just because your site is in maintenance mode does not mean it is not vulnerable.

Comment: If you're really paranoid about security I'm not sure Drupal/PHP is the best solution. You could use either the Static or Boost modules to convert your dynamic site into static (and thus completely safe) html files. That only works if you don't need users to be able to login.

Comment: if cron is configured, you will be receiving notifications of updates from the website. As has been said above, putting site in maintenance mode won't protect the site. Applying the update will protect the site

Comment: But what I want is that it's automated - that is, no person needs to apply the update himself.

Comment: right, let me check that.

Comment: of course we're talking about minimizing the risks.